# Open image for sharing

Tags: android, xamarin, share, preview

I have Android Xamarin application with imageview
OnClik I lunch intent to preview image

```
File file = new File(photoPath);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
intent.SetDataAndType(Uri.FromFile(file), "image/*");
intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NoHistory);
StartActivity(intent);
```

from apps I choose 'Gallery'
when the image is opend there are no sharing options
[image]

when I open image from device 'Gallery' has sharing options

[image]

Image is saved to SD card before preview.
what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Android version of it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27314877/share-images-from-gallery-in-android

Comment: did you solved?

Answer (score 2):

solution that worked for me

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.PutExtra(Intent.ActionView, photoPath);
intent.SetType("image/*");
StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Select Picture"));
```

now I get my image opend in gallery and I can use sharing options too

Answer (score 1):

Do it using `Intent.ACTION_SEND` and you'll get that sharing option.

Also try with `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
"Select Picture"), 1);
```

Comment: When i use ACTION_SEND Gallery is not among applications to choose
when i choose any other application i do not get preview, only send popup.
I am trying to get preview AND send options

Comment: Also try with `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`.

Comment: thank you for code,
but now it only opens all images on my device, free to borws,
i am trying to preview one image and to have share button asi is printscreened in question